# What library does docker use to render the pulling/downloading/extracting information on terminal

Tags: docker

I really like how when I run docker build/compose in terminal it shows the status as it downloads/extracts layers. Does anyone know what library is used to render this? Is it something open-source or part of docker source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is written in GO language and the STDOUT manipulation you see must be written using the [termbox](https://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go) package.

The manipulation is none other than moving the cursor to the desired position before writing to STDOUT.

`func SetCursor(x, y int)`

The effect is updating text- rather than appending text.